# What is ToString("N0") format?

Tags: c#, .net, number-formatting

This code is from Charles Pettzold's "Programming Windows Sixth Edition" book:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language) 
{ 
    return ((double)value).ToString("N0"); 
}
```

`ToString("N0")` is supposed to print the value with comma separators and no decimal points. I cannot find the reference to appropriate `ToString` overload and `"N0"` format in the documentation. Please point me to the right place in .NET documentation.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

Checkout the [`following article`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94.aspx) on MSDN about examples of the `N` format. This is also covered in the [`Standard Numeric Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) article.

Relevant excerpts:

```
//       Formatting of 1054.32179:
//          N:                     1,054.32 
//          N0:                    1,054 
//          N1:                    1,054.3 
//          N2:                    1,054.32 
//          N3:                    1,054.322
```

> When precision specifier controls the number of fractional digits in the result string, the result string reflects a number that is rounded to a representable result nearest to the infinitely precise result. If there are two equally near representable results:
>
> - On the .NET Framework and .NET Core up to .NET Core 2.0, the runtime selects the result with the greater least significant digit (that is, using MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).
> - On .NET Core 2.1 and later, the runtime selects the result with an even least significant digit (that is, using MidpointRounding.ToEven).

Comment: It would be nice to know that N0 of 1054.56, returns 1,055 and not 1,054. Quite relevant!

Answer (score 4):

This is where the documentation is:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

> The numeric ("N") format specifier converts a number to a string of
>   the form "-d,ddd,ddd.ddd…", where "-" indicates a negative number
>   symbol if required, "d" indicates a digit (0-9) ...

And this is where they talk about the default (2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimaldigits.aspx

```
      // Displays a negative value with the default number of decimal digits (2).
      Int64 myInt = -1234;
      Console.WriteLine( myInt.ToString( "N", nfi ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good start maybe

[Double.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3xb8436k.aspx)

Have a look in the examples for a number of different formating options [Double.ToString(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can find the list of formats [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94.aspx) (in the Double.ToString()-MSDN-Article) as comments in the example section.

Answer (score 0):

It is a sort of format specifier for formatting numeric results. There are additional specifiers [on the link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/formatting-numeric-results-table).

What `N` does is that it separates numbers into thousand decimal places according to your [CultureInfo](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=netframework-4.8) and represents only 2 decimal digits in floating part as is `N2` by rounding right-most digit if necessary.

`N0` does not represent any decimal place but rounding is applied to it.

Let's exemplify.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;


namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double x = 567892.98789;
            CultureInfo someCulture = new CultureInfo("da-DK", false);

            // 10 means left-padded = right-alignment
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format(someCulture, "{0:N} denmark", x));
            Console.WriteLine("{0,10:N} us", x); 

            // watch out rounding 567,893
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format(someCulture, "{0,10:N0}", x)); 
            Console.WriteLine("{0,10:N0}", x);

            Console.WriteLine(String.Format(someCulture, "{0,10:N5}", x));
            Console.WriteLine("{0,10:N5}", x);


            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

It yields,

```
567.892,99 denmark
567,892.99 us
   567.893
   567,893
567.892,98789
567,892.98789
```